# ¿Cómo lograr que los JPanel que creo se ponga uno debajo del otro?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy tratando de crear dinámicamente algunos componentes para presentarlos como una lista. Logro crear los componentes pero no puedo hacer que aparezcan uno debajo del otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
public void cargarLotes(List<ComparacionLotes>comparacionLotes){
    panelContenedor.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    for (ComparacionLotes cl : comparacionLotes) {
        ContenedorDeFila f = new ContenedorDeFila(cl);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470, 50));
        subPanel.add(f);
    }
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(subPanel);
    jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelContenedor.getSize()));
    panelContenedor.add(jScrollPane);

    panelContenedor.validate();
    this.validate();


}
```

Este clase es un panel y contiene los elementos que quiero mostrar. Es la fila que contendrá todos los objetos que requiero.

```
class ContenedorDeFila extends JPanel{

    ComparacionLotes cl;
    JLabel etiquetaLote;
    JLabel etiquetaExistencia;
    JTextField recuadroEntrada;


    UtilidadesTxt_ _recuadroEntrada;

    public ContenedorDeFila(ComparacionLotes cl) {
        this.cl = cl;
        generarFila();
    }

    private void generarFila() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        etiquetaLote = new JLabel();
        etiquetaExistencia = new JLabel();
        recuadroEntrada = new JTextField();

        //EntradaLoteIT eit = new EntradaLoteIT();
        //_recuadroEntrada = new UtilidadesTxt_(getCoordinador());
        //_recuadroEntrada.setComponente(recuadroEntrada);
        //_recuadroEntrada.setPermitirSoloNumeros(
        //        eit.getCantidadPDC().getLongitudDeCaracteres(), 
        //        eit.getCantidadPDC().getLongitudDeDecimales());

        // ASIGNAMOS LOS VALORES PARA LAS ETIQUETAS.
        etiquetaLote.setText(cl.getLote().getNombreParaMostrarLote());
        etiquetaExistencia.setText(">"+cl.getLote().getCantidad());


        add(etiquetaLote);
        add(etiquetaExistencia);
        add(recuadroEntrada);

        validate();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El FlowLayout te los acomoda siempre horizontalmente mientras haya espacio, intenta mejor con un BoxLayout

```
subPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```